# How to count days using datetime64[ns] with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, google-colaboratory

Uni student here, I have to analyze data for a Data Analytics course.
We have to work on a dataset about expeditions on mountains. I want to calculate how many days it took for the climbers to go from the basepoint to the highpoint (`expeditions['basecamp_date']`&`expeditions['highpoint_date']`).
I found a way to count the days but how can I put those values in a new column? (`expeditions['days_reach_top']`). I want to be able to calculate the mean etc afterwards.
Here is the code I have right now:

```
expeditions['basecamp_date']=pd.to_datetime(expeditions['basecamp_date'])
expeditions['highpoint_date']=pd.to_datetime(expeditions['highpoint_date'])
expeditions['termination_date']=pd.to_datetime(expeditions['termination_date'])

date_format = "%Y-%m-%d/ns"

a = datetime.strptime(str(expeditions['basecamp_date']), date_format)
b = datetime.strptime(str(expeditions['highpoint_date']), date_format)
delta = b - a
print (delta.days)

expeditions['days_reach_top']
```

I know it's not complete but it's giving me `ValueError("unconverted data remains: %s" %` and `ValueError("time data %r does not match format %r" %`. How can I fix the time format and make calculus with it?
For context here's what my dataset looks like:
[image]

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace

```
a = datetime.strptime(str(expeditions['basecamp_date']), date_format)
b = datetime.strptime(str(expeditions['highpoint_date']), date_format)
```

with

```
a = expeditions['basecamp_date']
b = expeditions['highpoint_date']
```

Comment: it keeps telling me 'strptime() argument 1 must be str, not Series'..

Comment: I think what you are doing in the lines defining `a` and `b` is superflous. I edited my answer, try it now.

Comment: thank you so much! dont know why I added so much unnecessary stuff haha im new, thanks for the help